# How to redirect with .htaccess wrong external urls containing an?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress website, and in the past I used a script that loaded in frame page the external urls using the folliwing string:
    http://www.mywebsite.com/?out=http://www.externaldomain.com/...
but it was used by spammers for their purposes so I had to disable it, but now -in the world- every link like the one above show my hompage. I need to redirect all urls that have that structure to a custom 404 page, like *if is ?out=http/...  THEN redirect to 404 url page*
Is it possible via .htaccess?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^out=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/error.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No problem, if it did solve your problem, you can the answer as being correct so other users with your problem would know you solved it.